# my sendemail function used multiple times returns redeclare or undefine var error

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to use my sendemail() function multiple times in my expired_account() function depending on what it finds.  First it checks for accounts expiring in 8 days, sends email, then checks for 1 day, sends email, then checks for expired accounts - sends email.

The first check for 8 days works.. the email is sent with no errors, but any other sendemail() returns an error which is either

include_once:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: mail in C:\www\dev\common.inc on line 4585 Fatal error: Call to a member function setFrom() on a non-object in C:\www\dev\common.inc on line 4585
```

or when i change include_once to just include:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PHPMailerAutoload() (previously declared in C:\www\dev\phpmailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php:24) in C:\www\dev\phpmailer\PHPMailerAutoload.php on line 31
```

My sendemail function:

```
function sendemail($wordwrap=50, $html=true, $to, $cc='', $cc2='', $cc3='', $subject, $body) {

include_once "phpmailer/phpmailer.inc";

global $systememail;
$fromname = "System Mail";

$mail->setFrom($systememail, $fromname);
$mail->addAddress($to);
if ($cc != "")
$mail->addCC($cc); //CC
if ($cc2 != "")
$mail->addCC($cc2); //CC
if ($cc3 != "")
$mail->addCC($cc3); //CC
$mail->WordWrap = $wordwrap;    // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML($html);           // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $body;

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        $maxTries = 3;
        for ($try=1; $try<=$maxTries; $try++) {
            usleep(5000);
            if ($mail->send()) {
            break;
            }
            if ($try >= 3) {
            exit;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code that executes sendemail() function:

```
if ($daysleft == 8) {
            //do this for 8 days left before contract ends
            $subject =  "Contract for $fullname expires in $daysleft days";
            $body = " Account expiring in $daysleft days";
    sendemail($wordwrap=50, $html=true, $email, $manageremail, '', '', $subject, $body);
    }

    if ($daysleft == 1) {
            //do this for 1 day left before contract ends
            $subject =  "Contract for $fullname expires in $daysleft days *FINAL NOTICE*";
            $body = "Account expiring in $daysleft days";
    sendemail($wordwrap=50, $html=true, $email, $manageremail, '', '', $subject, $body);
    }

    if ($todaydate >= $contractend_TS) {
            //do this for expired accounts.... :
            $subject =  "Contract for $fullname has expired";
            $body = "Contract for $fullname has expired";
    sendemail($wordwrap=50, $html=true, $email, $manageremail, '', '', $subject, $body);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `$mail` variable is set / initialized when you include your `phpmailer/phpmailer.inc` file.

As you use `include_once`, it will only be included the first time you call your function, so only the first time the `$mail` variable is set and the required object.

You should include the file outside of the function and send the `$mail` variable as a parameter to the function.

You would have to check if you need to *reset* your `$mail` variable before you use it a second time, that would depend on the mailer you are using.

Comment: I'm using PHPMailer ... i'll see what i can do. thanks for your help

Comment: I was missing $mail = new PHPMailer();  in the sendemail function... thanks buddy :)